# TS doesn't see added properties to the const object

Tags: typescript

A function should return object `{ a: number, b: number }`, so I'm creating the object and fill it up later:

```
const output = {};
output.a = 1;
output.b = 2;
return output;
```

But TS gives me the error:
`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Output': a, b ts(2739)`

I'm expecting TS to understand I've added required fields to the const object as the function is running.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript compiler doesn't consider the added properties based on runtime. One way to do it is to use the `as` keyword as follows:

```
const output = {} as { a: number, b: number };
```